# Rust / rusqlite: cannot move out of a shared reference

Tags: rust

I'm keeping a Connection wrapped in an Option in a property of a struct and I'm having trouble closing the Connection. I have checked a lot of answers here at stackoverflow for the general problem but I couldn´t get it working for my case.

Here's a minimal example to reproduce the error:

```
use rusqlite::Connection;

struct Db {
    c: Option<Connection>
}

impl Db {

    pub fn new() -> Self {
        return Db { c: None }
    }

    pub fn open(&mut self) {
        self.c = Some(Connection::open("test.db").unwrap());
    }

    pub fn close(&mut self) {
        self.c.as_ref().unwrap().close();
    }

}

fn main() {
    let mut d= Db::new();
    d.open();
    d.close();
}
```

I get the following output, using Rust 1.61.0 (`Arch Linux rust 1:1.61.0-1`) with Cargo and rusqlite (`rusqlite = { version = "0.27.0", features = ["bundled"] }`)

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of a shared reference
   --> foo.rs:18:9
    |
18  |         self.c.as_ref().unwrap().close();
    |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-------
    |         |                        |
    |         |                        value moved due to this method call
    |         move occurs because value has type `Connection`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
    |
note: this function takes ownership of the receiver `self`, which moves value
   --> ~.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/rusqlite-0.27.0/src/lib.rs:725:18
    |
725 |     pub fn close(self) -> Result<(), (Connection, Error)> {
    |                  ^^^^

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0507`.
```

The function close() from the rusqlite library which the output refers to looks like this:

```
   /// Close the SQLite connection.
    ///
    /// This is functionally equivalent to the `Drop` implementation for
    /// `Connection` except that on failure, it returns an error and the
    /// connection itself (presumably so closing can be attempted again).
    ///
    /// # Failure
    ///
    /// Will return `Err` if the underlying SQLite call fails.
    #[inline]
    pub fn close(self) -> Result<(), (Connection, Error)> {
        self.flush_prepared_statement_cache();
        let r = self.db.borrow_mut().close();
        r.map_err(move |err| (self, err))
    }
```

How can I fix this error without changing the general architecture, that is keeping the Connection wrapped in an Option in a property of a struct and closing it via an implementation method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The `Connection::close` method](https://docs.rs/rusqlite/0.27.0/rusqlite/struct.Connection.html#method.close) consumes `self`, so you have to take the wrapped value inside `self.c` out in order to call `close` on it. After `take`ing, the `c` becomes `None`.

```rust
use rusqlite::Connection;

struct Db {
    c: Option<Connection>,
}

impl Db {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        return Db { c: None };
    }

    pub fn open(&mut self) {
        self.c = Some(Connection::open("test.db").unwrap());
    }

    pub fn close(&mut self) {
        self.c.take().unwrap().close().unwrap();
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut d = Db::new();
    d.open();
    d.close();
}
```

[Documentation of `std::option::Option::take`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.take)